# Why does github/bitbucket etc by default require generated keys as "passwords" for cloning private repos? Instead of password + 2FA?

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

Basically I recently had to explain to a non coder client(freelance work) how to download a private github repo for the Unity Project I'm working on, via sourctree GUI. Now at the time I didn't realize he would need to generate a OAuth token for his password, so it ended up not working at first.

But looking back, why is this the norm? I can understand the desire to have different access tokens with different permissions, but shouldn't that be an opt in thing by the repo owner or github user? Wouldn't simply the normal account password + 2FA requirement solve the vast majority of security concerns?

And why does the repo owner account, not need to generate any access tokens to clone/push etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Git performs an authentication operation against GitHub or Bitbucket, it usually uses Basic authentication.  In other words, the value sent is a username and password of some type.  As a result, there's no standardized place to provide a two-factor authentication token that's independent of the password field.

Moreover, if a user were cloning a large number of repositories (e.g., as part of onboarding at a company), each one of those clone operations would start at a different time and therefore require a different 2FA code.  That would mean that the user would have to actively monitor their progress and enter a code from their phone, use their YubiKey, use TouchID or Windows Hello, or some other 2FA mechanism, which would be inconvenient.

Using a securely generated token or password is also the preferred approach for Google Apps and other services where 2FA is enabled but there aren't good options other than a password for authentication.  This is also the case for many language package sites, such as crates.io, which provides only random tokens.

I can't speak for Bitbucket, but it is *currently* possible for a GitHub user to use their password for cloning over HTTPS if they don't have 2FA set up.  However, GitHub is removing that ability because if the password is leaked, an attacker can log into the web interface, change passwords, conduct spam and abuse, and a whole bunch of other activities just with that password.  In addition, many users who don't use 2FA also don't use a password manager, so they are likely to use similar passwords when their old password has been compromised, which leads to another compromise.  A token doesn't permit changing the user's password and it's scoped so that exposure has less impact.

Compromised accounts are a big problem both for users and hosting sites.  If a user is compromised, anything they have access to could be downloaded, including their private code or their employer's private code, causing massive financial loss.  In addition, bad actors try to sell the abilities of compromised accounts to sell stars on repositories, harass users, host malware, and a bunch of other undesirable activities.  This requires a lot of effort to combat so the site doesn't become a cesspit of spam and abuse.  Additionally, once this activity occurs, the account will generally be suspended or restricted, which then causes problems for users and potentially their employers.

So ideally this would be a decision by the user, but because many users have bad password practices and lax security and the consequences of that on the whole are bad for the entire community, it's necessary for hosting sites to act and adopt more robust security measures.